# regex - find invalid character

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

Using

```
regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]*$'
```

in below script file I am checking if a given string has any invalid characters or not.

```
str="$1"

regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]+$'

if [[ $str =~ $regex ]]
then
  echo "matches"
  echo "Match: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
else
  echo "doesn't match"
fi
```

As there is an option to get matched string using BASH_REMATCH, is there any option to get which invalid character was present in the string if string does not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see a built-in option, so here's one idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="$1"

regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]+$'

if [[ $str =~ $regex ]]
then
  echo "matches"
  echo "Match: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
else
  echo "doesn't match"
  for (( i = 0; i < ${#str}; i++ )) do
    c=${str:$i:1}
    if [[ ! $c =~ $regex ]]
    then
      echo Non-matching character at index $i: "$c"
    fi
  done
fi
```

It simply loops through the `$str` character by character, comparing that character to the `$regex`.

Comment: It works. I thought there would be some API, but this is great.

Comment: can you help me? what is meant here by *valid character*? just any character which can be matched by the regex? or like a literal invalid byte sequence?

Comment: I used "invalid" to mean "not valid", meaning "not matching the regex"; sorry for the confusion. Perhaps I should edit "Invalid" to "Non-matching"

Comment: was it your question? i dont blame you at all - i just thought you might understand. the question is how to find *invalid characters* - you just used the verbiage presented you. makes sense - i was just wondering what it meant. so the goal here is to strip all matching chars from the value until none or only non-matching remain?

Comment: Not my question, though I tried to edit it a bit to make it clearer (!). I understood the goal to be: if a given string does *not* match a given regex, then show which character(s) did not match.

Comment: well, thats definitely what your thing does - thats why i voted for it. yours is the only answer here that even gave me a clue about what the question even was. anyway - looks fun. i think ill try it. and your edit to the question didnt change the verbiage. that was in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can negate your regular expression to find the *first* invalid char

Your current regex

```
$ str="in below script file I am checking if a given string has any invalid characters or not."
$ regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]+$'
$ [[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo pass || echo fail
fail
```

Fails on the spaces. Negate the regex: remove the line anchors and the trailing `+` quantifier; negate the bracket expression -- we have the set of *not* valid chars:

```
regex='[^]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]'
```

Then

```
$ [[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "fail: found '${BASH_REMATCH[0]}'"
fail: found ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cls='],_[:alnum:]!^`@{}=().;/~|[-'

while getopts : na "-$str"
do    case $OPTARG   in ([!$cls])
           printf %s\\n "$OPTARG"
      esac
done
```

The shell's `getopts` options parser works by iteratively stripping a string character by character and assigning its most recently stripped char to a shell variable. And so if you want to take a string apart, `getopts` can make it pretty convenient. All you have to do afterward is test the current iteration's character for *validity*. If it matches, leave it alone, but, if `!` not, `printf` it.

Answer (score 0):

This will catch the chars that match:

```
regex=']0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-'

echo "$str" | grep -oP '^['"$regex"']*'
```

Capturing in a var and removing from the beginning of the original string:

```
head="$(echo "$str" | grep -oP '^['"$regex"']*')"

tail="${str#"$head"}"
```

Finally, get first char that failed:

```
failedChar="${tail:0:1}"          # higher shells method.
failedChar="${tail"${tail#?}"}"    # Alternative method.
```

---

Using BASH_REMATCH

```
str="Testing that this is working."
regex=']0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-'
[[ $str =~ ^[$regex]* ]]

head="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"

tail="${str#"$head"}"

failedChar="${tail%"${tail#?}"}"

echo "fc |$failedChar| at position ${#head}"
```